# How to solve the init_by_lua error in kong?

Tags: docker-compose, kong

I have created a docker-compose file to spin up **Postgres, kong-migration and kong** in a container. All the containers were up and I was able to use kong for the first time. But yesterday onwards, I am getting the below error:

> stack traceback:  [C]: in function 'error'
> /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/utils/migrations.lua:16: in
> function 'check_state'    /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/init.lua:432: in
> function 'init'   init_by_lua:3: in main chunk nginx: [error]
> init_by_lua error:
> /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/utils/migrations.lua:16: Database
> needs bootstrapping or is older than Kong 1.0.
>
> To start a new installation from scratch, run 'kong migrations
> bootstrap'.
>
> To migrate from a version older than 1.0, migrated to Kong 1.5.0
> first.  If you still have 'apis' entities, you can convert them to
> Routes and Services using the 'kong migrations migrate-apis' command
> in Kong 1.5.0.

Answer (score 1):

Can't tell without the compose file, but the error is clear, Kong is connecting to uninitialized database. So it needs bootstrapping using `kong migrations bootstrap`.

Could be that the order in which the containers are started is wrong?

Comment: Please run "kong migrations bootstrap" it will initialize the empty database.